# Does Druid reatime node and history node cause hotspot

Tags: druid

Apache Druid's nodes include realtime nodes(response for receiving and searching realtime data) and historical nodes(response for searching historical data). 
My question is that if I have a lot of historical queries, would that cause the historical nodes too hot and realtime nodes spare. Or say if I have a lot of queries of realtime, than the historical nodes would be spare and realtime nodes would be very busy.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU utilization of historical nodes in Druid depends on three factors:

- The volume of the data that they hold (that depends on the [data retention](http://druid.io/docs/latest/operations/rule-configuration.html): e. g. you could keep 1 day, or 1 month, of 1 year of the data, etc.)
- Specific configuration of disk space / memory / CPU capacity of the historical nodes.
- The volume and complexity of the queries to the nodes.

With realtime nodes the situation is approximately the same:

- Data ingestion intensity (volume of data per unit of time)
- Memory / CPU capacity of the realtime nodes (disk space is less important)
- The volume and complexity of the queries to the nodes.

This means that you could control the CPU utilization by:

- Changing the data retention in the cluster.
- Choosing historical and realtime instance configuration with different disk / memory volume / CPU capacity ratio. There is a certain freedom of doing that in cloud environments such as AWS, GCP and Azure.

  - You could [orginize historical "tiers"](https://medium.com/p/ef594ce298f2#95fa) to tradeoff query speed and cluster costs down this path.
- If your historical nodes still have spare CPU resources, you could actually share them e. g. for a batch-processing Hadoop or Spark cluster, [as described in this article](https://metamarkets.com/2017/druid-and-spark-together-mixing-analytics-workflows/).